# For In Loop Uses in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, for-in-loop

What are some of the practical for in loop use cases in JavaScript?  They're bad for arrays since they ignore undefined keys and return numerable properties of the array object.  I've never seen them used in any production code.  Have they been all but deprecated by developers?

Comment: Use them when you need to iterate over an object to behave like a hash table. For example, when you get JSON back from a request, and you want to act on all the properties of an object when you are not sure _what_ those properties will exactly be.  --- not at all deprecated.

Comment: `for in` is for objects, not arrays.

Comment: Well, yeah it's not the best way to handle arrays, but I find it extremely useful for objects

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Now that I think about it, I have used them to iterate through JSONs

Comment: Reflection. That's it for the most part

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are best for iterating over Javascript or JSON objects, like `{"foo":bar,"baz":boo}`, but not for arrays, see more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea) for more info about that.

They are best done like this:

```
var obj={"foo":bar,"baz":boo}
for(var key in obj){
   //hasOwnProperty ensures that it exists and bad stuff doesn't happen with deleted properties
   if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)){
       obj[key].doSomething();
   }
}
```

Douglas Crockford has a very good page on this [here](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/09/26/for-in-intrigue/). For arrays, they should never be used, but they are very useful for objects, especially if you don't know what order the keys will be in, or what keys will be there. For arrays, just do this

```
for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
//do some stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) says:

> Iterates over the enumerable properties of an object, in arbitrary
>   order. For each distinct property, statements can be executed.

You may also check **[Exploring JavaScript for-in loops](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/01/04/exploring-javascript-for-in-loops/)**

```
var str = "hello!", spreadOut = "";

for (var index in str) {
    (index > 0) && (spreadOut += " ")
    spreadOut += str[index];
}

spreadOut; //"h e l l o !"
```

You may refer this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea) where CMS has explained it:

> The purpose of the for-in statement is to enumerate over object
>   properties, this statement will go up in the prototype chain,
>   enumerating also inherited properties, thing that sometimes is not
>   desired.

Answer (score 1):

It is useful for iterating objects where the iteration is not dependent on order. It is useful in a few ways.

The variable used in the for in statement is the key to the current value.

The shorthand notation can save a few characters in the .js file.

It can be more readable.